# DFA with limited states

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, automata, finite-automata

Lets $L_z \ := \{ a^i b^i c^i : 0 \leq i < z \}$

$\{a,b,c\} \in \sum^*$

there is a DFA with $\frac{z(z+1)}{2}+1$ states - How can I prove this?

And I need largest possible number $n_z$, for which i can prove that every NFA, which accepts $L_z$, have $n_z$ states, at least!

But first I need to show that $n_z = \frac{z(z+1)}{2}$
 right?

Comment: You mean $a, b, c \in \Sigma$ ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Constructing a DFA

There is an algorithm to construct a [minimal DFA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dfa_minimization) for a regular language. In this case, it isn't too hard to come up with a DFA with $z(z+1)/2$ states.

Observe that $L_z = \{\epsilon, abc, aabbcc, \ldots, a^{z-1}b^{z-1}c^{z-1}\}$. Once you know the number of $a$'s at the beginning of the word, you know how many $b$'s and $c$'s to expect. Here's a simple DFA built from this observation (with $z' = z-1$):

[image: automaton]
<sup>[[source](https://github.com/akerbos/sesketches/blob/gh-pages/src/cs_1740.tikz)]</sup>

Following the usual convention, if there is no transition for a particular letter from a particular node, the automaton goes to a sink state.

This automaton has $n$ states reached after reading $0$ to $z-1$ letters `a` ($k,0,0$ for $0\le k\le z-1$), and branches of length $2k$ for $0 \le k \le z-1$ to read the right number of `b`'s and `c`'s ($k,i,0$ and $k,k,i$ for $1 \le i \le k \le z-1$). That's a total of $z + \sum_{k=0}^{z-1} (2k) = z^2$ states, plus one to account for the implicit sink state.

It's possible to compress this automaton a bit.

> Notice that every side branch finishes by counting the `c`'s. Instead of tracking how many `c`'s have already been seen, think in terms of how many `c`'s are left to read. You can merge all the states of the form $k,k,k-n$, for all $k \ge 1$, into a state $-,n$ from which $n$ occurrences of `c` must be read. In particular, there will be only two final states: one for the empty word, and one after reading the right number of `c`'s. In this automaton, the $k$th side branch has $k$ edges to read the `b`'s (so $k-1$ states, as the start state belongs to the `a` trunk, and the end state belongs to the `c` collector), and there are $z-1$ transitions to count the `c`'s (so $z$ states, corresponding to $0$ through $z-1$ `c`'s left).

The total number of states in this automaton (including the sink state) is $z + \sum_{k=1}^{z-1} (k-1) + (z-1) + 1 = z(z+1)/2 + 1$.

#### Constructing an NFA

In other words, $n_z$ is the number of states in a minimal NFA that recognizes $L_z$. If you have a DFA with $N$ states, that's an NFA with $N$ states. So $n_z \le z(z+1)/2+1$. For most languages, a minimal NFA is smaller than a minimal DFA: nondeterminism adds expressive power in terms of how much you can accomplish with a number of states.

In this particular case, it happens that the minimal DFA above is also a minimal NFA (if I didn't make a mistake). Here's an informal proof.

> Consider the states in the middle of reading the `b`'s. When reading $a^k b^i | b^{k-i} c^k$, where $|$ represents the current position, the state must account for both $k$ and $i$, to remember both the number of seen `a`'s (which is necessary, because we'll need to count the `c`'s later) and the number of seen `b`'s (or, equivalently, the number of `b`'s still required). This requires distinct states for every $(i,k)$ such that $1 \le i \lt k \le z-1$. In addition, there must be $z-1$ states to count the `a`'s at the beginning, and $z-1$ states to count the `c`'s at the beginning, plus a sink state. That's a total of $z(z+1)/2+1$ states.

Answer (score 5):

I will give you an indication: first, write an automaton which recognizes exactly the language $M_n=\{b^nc^n\}$. How many states has this automaton?

Now use the [pumping lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages) to prove that this is the minimum number of states for $M_n$. The pumping lemma can be refined for automata with fixed number of states which is exaclty wikipedia's $p$ in "there exists $p$ such that ...".

Use the automata for $M_n$ to build your DFA for $L_z$.

EDIT: I removed the last part: you can use the pumping lemma to prove the minimum size for $M_n$ but not (at least not directly) for $L_z$.

To prove that you got the minimum size for the automaton, you can reason about the languages corresponding to each state, corresponding to the residual languages $w^{-1}L_z$. The number of such residual languages is a lower bound on the number of states for $L_z$.

Comment: How would you use the pumping lemma to prove the automaton minimal?

Comment: @vonbrand Please don't abuse the answer feature for commenting! Regarding your comment, I think that you might have material for a new question there.